# QML - Wrapmode not compelling the text into the rectangle

Tags: qt, qml, word-wrap

I am posting because I want a text the be wrap into a rectangle (if the text is too long, it will be cut and the end of it won't be display)
For now I tried with :

```
Rectangle {
    id: form
    property alias px: form.x
    property alias py: form.y
    property alias pheight: form.height
    property alias pwidth: form.width
    property ItemControl itemControl

    color: itemControl.backgroundColor
    border.width: 1
    border.color: itemControl.color
    radius: 1
    Text {
        id: text_field
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text:itemControl.text
        color: itemControl.color
        font.pixelSize: 16
        font.family: robotoMono.name
        font.bold: false
        wrapMode: text_field.WordWrap
        maximumLineCount: 1
    }
}
```

But I don't have the expected result. The text is still continuing after the end of the rectangle. Does anyone knows how to compel the text into the rectangle ?

[image]

Comment: I've attempted an answer, but I couldn't really test your code specifically (do consider making it a [mre] next time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used Text.WordWrap but the text only contains one word (the `.` and underscores aren't treated as word separators). `Text.Wrap` and `Text.WrapAnywhere` may be more appropriate in this case. Moreover, `maximumLineCount: 1` will limit `Text` to only show one line.

Consider making the font smaller, the rectangle larger, or redesign the UI for this bit.